# Django | can't see form {{form.username}}

Tags: python, html, django, web

I can't render form username on the template. like I want to to render the form fields automatically which I defined in `forms.py` file but it's not working. here you go below for my detailed files
**forms.py**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

## My views

from .forms import CreateUserForm

## Registration

def regPage(request):
form = CreateUserForm()

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'web/car-finder-home.html')
```

html

```
<form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="mb-4">
                                  <label class="form-label text-light" for="signup-name">Username</label>
                                  {{ form.username }}
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-4">
                                  <label class="form-label text-light" for="signup-email">Email address</label>
                                  <input class="form-control form-control-light" type="email" id="signup-email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-4">
                                  <label class="form-label text-light" for="signup-password">Password <span class="fs-sm opacity-50">min. 8 char</span></label>
                                  <div class="password-toggle">
                                      <input class="form-control form-control-light" type="password" id="signup-password" minlength="8" required />
                                      <label class="password-toggle-btn" aria-label="Show/hide password"> <input class="password-toggle-check" type="checkbox" /><span class="password-toggle-indicator"></span> </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-4">
                                  <label class="form-label text-light" for="signup-password-confirm">Confirm password</label>
                                  <div class="password-toggle">
                                      <input class="form-control form-control-light" type="password" id="signup-password-confirm" minlength="8" required />
                                      <label class="password-toggle-btn" aria-label="Show/hide password"> <input class="password-toggle-check" type="checkbox" /><span class="password-toggle-indicator"></span> </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check form-check-light mb-4">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="agree-to-terms" required />
                                  <label class="form-check-label" for="agree-to-terms">
                                      <span class="opacity-70">By joining, I agree to the</span> <a href="#" class="text-light">Terms of use</a> <span class="opacity-70">and</span> <a href="#" class="text-light">Privacy policy</a>
                                  </label>
                              </div>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100" type="submit">Sign up</button>
                          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't add in core urls.py

```
from my_app_name import urls
urlpatterns = [
     path('cars/', views.regPage, name="register"),
]
```

xD

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm
def regPage(request): 
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # consider adding a redirect page here this is a good approach

    else:
        context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'web/car-finder-home.html',context) # your forgot to add context
```

Now inside your template you can access the form...

Comment: No still I can't access, but thanks a lot!

Comment: did you see the username when you rendered {{ form.as_p }} ???

Comment: no i just forgot it to add to a core views xD